# Why do we use "has" for a plural subject?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have a statement with an error, and I don't understand the explanation given to me about what is wrong with it.

> A letter of recommendation b)/ from the principal and c)/ the Head of English department have helped him to d)/ get this lucrative job. e)/ No error

The answer for the question about the above sentence shows we have to use *has* instead of *have: have helped him to* should be *has helped him to.* This is what I don't understand.

My question is that *has* is used to represent the singular form, so why do we have to use *has*? In the above sentence, "the principal and Head of English department" denotes two people — so why do we have to use *has*?

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that this question was [edited](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/357998/revisions) prior to migration to ELL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"HAS" here refers to "a letter of recommendation", which is singular.

Taking away those two people may help you see it better: "A letter of recommendation **has** helped him..."

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The  complete subject of the sentence is *letter of recommendation *, which is singular, so the correct form of the verb is **has*, also singular.  The element *from the principal and the Head of English Department* is a prepositional phrase and has no bearing on the verb form.